# How to analyse untyped buffer in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I am working on a C application that writes and reads a lot of binary data to files. The file accesses are done by pages, like in a database.

Now, suppose we read a page like

`char *buf = malloc(PAGE_SIZE);
 pread(fd, buf, PAGE_SIZE, nth * PAGE_SIZE);`

What I want to know is: Is there a convenient way to analyse the contents of `buf` reinterpreting them as other types in GDB? For instance, how can I check that the `double` value at 0x3F from the beginning of this page is `3.14`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
print *((double*)buf+0x3f)
```

- (buf+0x3f) - pointer to interesting part of memory
- (double*)(ptr) - casting it as pointer to double
- "*(ptr)" - accessing it's value